# Do left over unenrcypted files get copied to another drive?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I understand when you delete a file you do not actually delete it, a full format or random data needs to be written to the same spot to really "erase" it.

So if I have a gpg encrypted file on a plain HDD and decrypt it once and delete the decrypted file. It would still be possible for someone to run software to get that decrypted file that I "deleted".

What happens if the decrypted file (that I already deleted) was in a folder  and I copy that folder to a flash drive. Will the flash drive now also have the decrypted "deleted" file that is still on my HDD?

Comment: If you were using on-the-fly encryption like luks, veracrypt (truecrypt), or ecryptfs, encfs, bitlocker? then you wouldn't have any decrypted files to worry about. Or decrypt files to ram only

Answer (score 1):

Although files generally represent actual data areas on the disk, **folders do not.** A folder only represents *a list of files*.

Most operating systems do not have an operation to copy a whole folder (neither the contained data nor the file list) – instead the file manager requests a list of files, then copies each file individually.

Because deleting a file means it'll no longer show up in the folder's "list of files", programs copying the folder won't see deleted files either – so nothing about them will be copied.